# Need help in port forwarding webserver from my rpi to external ip

Tags: webserver, portforwarding, raspberry-pi4, port80

I need help port forwarding my webserver from my local ip to external ip.
I have already tried setting up rules in my router for port 8080 (this is the current port for local ip as well (http://localhost:8080)) (Image Attached)
I am using Huawei Router: HG8145V5
I cannot access the webpage from my external ip it shows site cant be reached took too long to respond.
I'm sure its something wrong or extra needed with the port forwarding but cannot find out why.
The webpage is running on apache2.

[Port Forward Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmJ2W.png) 
[Webpage Running on 192.168.1.13:8080](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLIJU.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out i needed to unable dmz in forwarding rules to enable networking port forwards.